# Rails 3: Search in a query result

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, search

This is my query result (note the "includes"):

```
 @example_cars_collection = Car.where("name like ? ", "#{params[:car_name]}%").includes(:brand, :color, :shop)
```

Now, I want to find a car which brand is "Opel" in @example_cars_collection without doing any query... how can I do that?

I try with...

```
 @example_cars_collection.where(:brand_id => Brand.where("name like ? ", "#{params[:brand_name]}%").select(:code))
```

...and I obtain the correct results but obviously I am doing a new query... so my question is if is possible doing searches into a query results.

any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build an array based on the results with `to_a` and then use any `Array` methods:

```
@example_cars_collection.to_a.select { |car| car.brand.name.start_with?(params[:brand_name) }
```

Keep in mind that if you exclude `brand` from the included associations when fetching `@example_cars_collection` then this code would result in N+1 queries fetching each `brand` when doing `car.brand`.

Also, if you don't do `to_a`, but pass a block to `select`, the framework will delegate the call to `Array#select` instead of the sql related select.

Comment: Thanks Pablo for your answer!

Comment: and... if I want return the Brand objects collection from @example_cars_collection instead Car objects? is it possible?

Comment: Reusing `@example_cars_collection`? In that case I would do `@example_cars_collection.map(&:brand).uniq`. However, I would suggest using a query specifically designed query to retrieve the brands whose car name starts with something.

Comment: Thanks! I will try with your suggestion.

Comment: But.. why you prefer do a new query if in @example_cars_collection is include the Brands? thanks!

Comment: To leverage having to iterate over an array, building a new array, and then removing duplicated elements. It depends on the amount of cars you will have and the workload of the DB. `Brand.joins(:car).where("#{ Car.table_name }.name like ? ", "#{params[:car_name]}%").uniq`